# Visual studio python module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to setup a python debugger. I downloaded a package `python -m pip install matplotlib` and when it was done it said the script f2py.exe is installed and then it give the location then says which is not on PATH. Consider adding this directory to PATH. I am not sure about what path is. How do I add this to PATH?

Comment: Visual studio code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Does it under the `Scripts` folder contained in the python environment?

And you have not added this path into the system environment variable path?

Such as this path:

```
C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts
```